# Accidentaly deleted some files in var/lib

Tags: package-management, gnome-terminal

I accidentally deleted some files in var/lib. I don't know what I have deleted. Gnome-terminal too then disappeared since I messed up with Gnome-Purge. I then installed xterm using TTY. But then when I try to install some package, Unmet dependencies 'Try apt-fix broken install' with no package name. I do not want to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: You should try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` without a package name. If you suspect that other packages have been damaged, try `sudo dpkg -C [package]`. This should verify the completeness of the files that belong to package `[package]`.

Comment: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` returns: `installed python3-pip package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127`
`Errors were encountered while processing:`
`/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pip_9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1_all.deb`
`E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)`

Comment: `sudo dpkg -C` returned: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XLiR.jpg)

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip`.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip` returned `subprocess returned error exit status 127 Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pip_9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1_all.deb E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)`

Comment: We want to know what the error message is, so dig deeper. Do `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pip_9.0.1-2.3-ubuntu1_all.deb`.

Comment: dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pip_9.0.1-2.3-ubuntu1_all.deb':No such file or directory

Comment: Check the filename, I'm typing this on my phone.

Comment: http://imgur.com/sMu2bOJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92970/discussion-between-yolo-and-jos).